# Htaccess, rewrite and show 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Sorry if this is a duplicate, may be I'm using the wrong keywords, but I was unable to find a solution.

My question is how (using Apache; .htaccess) to achieve the following:

I have a file called show_results.php, and I want to:
Rewrite show_results.php to /results and when someone tries to access show_results.php to bring a 404 error (but /results must work correctly).

I've tried many different ways, but with no luck - when I rewrite, I'm able to access to original page. When I try to redirect the original page to 404 page, the "rewrited" page is showing 404 as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To return 404 for any/dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /.+?\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ -[R=404,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I want to redirect the original page to a native 404 error? Is that possible?

Comment: Sorry. I'll explain better. This is what I want exactly to happen - when I access /results to open show_results.php, when I access show_results.php directly to cause a 404 error (needs to be done with pure htacess). Thanks!!